# Delay Updating element slugs and URIs Job

Tags: plugin-feedme, import, tasks, queue

On a large website, after using feedme to import some content it immediatelly triggers the "Updating element slugs and URIs" process that takes very long time to complete. Is there a way to postpone or temporary disable this task and do the import first?

Answer (score 1):

You can try disabling Craft's queue temporarily by adding `'runQueueAutomatically' => false` to general.php, then trigger the feed [via the command line](https://docs.craftcms.com/feed-me/v4/feature-tour/trigger-import-via-cron.html#console-command).

Without testing this *might* prevent the 'Updating element slugs and URIs' job, but in any case – doing it this way you should see better performance overall.

p.s. if you add `--verbose` to the end of the command you can see what it's doing.

Comment: Thanks. Just tried. Is still tirggers the updating elements slugs tasks.

Comment: That's a shame. Did you find it works faster? This job has to run, so doing it on the command line is still the best way.

Comment: The import itself was already fast. These additional tasks are killing everything.

Comment: @MarkH. did you ever find a good solution to this?